# Moving Replicated database in SQL Server Transactional Replication

Tags: sql-server, replication

I have a scenario where I need to move the published database (Transactional Replication) to another server, which is having upgraded Windows and SQL Server installed.
Current config is:
Windows 2012 R2 and SQL Server 2012

New config will be:
Windows 2016 and SQL Server 2016.

Just to let you know subscribers are already in SQL Server 2016.

Now the question is, is there any way to move the replicated databases from the old server to the new one without breaking the replication?

Edit:

Forgot to mention the reason behind "not breaking the replication" the thing is we have Temporal enabled at subscriber end, and we don't want to reinitialize the subscribers anyhow.

The main reason for moving is that we want minimum downtime that will be required for patching, so we are building another server with Win 2016 and SQL Server 2016 and thinking of moving all the databases without removing replication.

Comment: You mention "move" So I assume you will move to new server, so there's no way to have the replicated databases configured as they were in a single step. However the good thing is that you already have your replicated DBs in a new environment so there's no need to resync again. I'd try to script the replication and then apply the scripts in the new server.

Comment: Also, you always need to be able to recreate a replication topology in a reasonable amount of time.  So you might want to do that just to be sure you've got the process ready and tested.